# Azure "Easy Tables" Rest API body

Tags: api, rest, azure

I am currently experimenting with Azure's new "Easy Tables". I have read that it's completely RESTful and I am fully capable of "GET"ting the data in the tables but somehow, I'm not sure how to insert the data I tried using "POST" but no matter what I put into the "data" part of my curl request, it always says

```
{"error":"An item to insert was not provided"}
```

Can someone tell me how the body should look like? I'm really getting desperate here...

My table looks like this:

```
id | createdAt | updatedAt | version | deleted | orgID
```

notice that only orgID is a column inserted by me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in wich plataform are you working? every App (Mobiel, Web, API) has a SDK to include that will make your dev life happier :)

Comment: do you have a "get" example around? I can get all records only, but I want to query on a specific field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what a request would look like using curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
    "id" :"1111",
    "orgID" : "1234"
}' "http://<your_site_host>/tables/<tablename>?zumo-api-version=2.0.0"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$urlAzure = "https://<your_app>.azurewebsites.net/tables/<your_table>";
$data = array (
  '<column1>' => <some_text>,
  '<column2>' => <some_text>
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'content' => json_encode( $data ),
      'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n"
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result= file_get_contents($urlAzure, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
```